# Lorentz norm of a monotone non-increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In Terence Tao's notes on harmonic analysis (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes1.pdf) problem 6.2 on page 18 asks a (what I suspect to be easy) [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIZD2.png):

if $f: \mathbf{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{+}$ is a monotone non-increasing function, show that 
$$\lVert f\rVert_{L^{p,q}(X,\mu)} = \lVert f(t)t^{1/p}\rVert_{L^{q}(\mathbf{R}^{+},\frac{dt}{t})} $$

Following his cue, I'm trying to prove this first for a smoother function, but I'm having a hard time applying the hypothesis and working with the distribution function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I'll remember that for next time